# Convert row of pyspark dataframe to python list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like the one shown below:

```
ID    ColA      ColB     ColC
1      23        45       69
2      34        56       43
3      46        67       89
```

I want to create one additional column which will have values of colA to ColC stored as list as shown below.

```
ID    ColA      ColB     ColC   Result
1      23        45       69    [23,45,69]
2      34        56       43    [34,56,43]
3      46        67       89    [46,67,89]
```

In pandas we can do this by using df['Result'] = df[['ColA','ColB','ColC']].values.tolist().

How to do this in pyspark dataframe?

Comment: you can use the [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html#pyspark-sql-functions-array) function.

Answer (score 1):

```
sdf.withColumn('Result', *[array(sdf.drop('ID').columns)]).show(truncate=False)
```